# how to unwrap a wall to get a consistent texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

Hello I am new to Blender, can someone please tell me how to unwrap correctly?

I want to texture a wall but it doesn't work as I desire. If I just unwrap the whole plane, the image just looks strange and stretched.

[image]

[image]

[image]

i want the pattern to be like this but without "the slice" looks

Comment: you don't need to divide your surface, if you keep a unique quad and unwrap it, you can duplicate your pattern as soon as you play with the size of the quad in the UV/Image Editor. Also, it looks like your picture is not correctly repeatable, the right side looks brighter than the left.

Comment: It's actually quite hard to read your imagination. Please use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/134192/edit) below your question to add a little more information about what you expect to see.

Comment: your texture its not seamless, though try this addon to make it seamless enough http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.com/2015/05/addon-make-seamless-textures-image-edit.html also yeah you dont need to add more supporting edges with 4 vertices its enough.

Comment: thank you so much for the answers but i really don't understand about quad and the addon that i've installed doesn't wanna show up.